# I declared the val here, so that i can use the val e11 in all the function but it get crashes and why?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, declaration, kotlin-android-extensions

what to do so?
I declared the val here, so that i can use the val e11 in all the function but it get crashes and why?

````
   //val e11=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.e1)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lifecycle)
       val b11=findViewById<Button>(R.id.b1)
       b11.setOnClickListener{
           startActivity(Intent(this,another::class.java))

    }}
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        Toast.makeText(this, "am started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Toast.makeText(this, "am resumed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
val e1=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.e1)
        e1.setText("")
    }
}```
````

Comment: This is because you are trying to find view id before view gets created. 
//val e11=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.e1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private val e11 : EditText by lazy { findViewById<EditText>(R.id.e1) }
```

Comment: I not 100% sure, but could it be that `val` will fail because e11 should not be final and be a `var`?

Comment: @MarcelHofgesang Root cause was findViewById. If you access it before the view gets created/inflated, it will fail/crash. You can either use lateinit or lazy declaration for e11 variable. 

in lateinit, you have to init before using it,
in lazy it will init at first usage and remember its value for further usage.

Comment: Hope this Works....val e11 by lazy{ findViewById<EditText>(R.id.e11)

Answer (score 0):

As @Kishan Maurya stated out in the comments, you are trying to find a view before the view gets created in your `onCreate` function. A solution could be to declare e11 globally and initiate it in your `onCreate` like it is most common. Or you try out @Kishan Maurya's answer.

```
lateinit var e11 : EditText // declare var e11 globally
// lateint is a keyword to tell that this var will be initialized later
// you need a var instead of val, because e11 should not be final

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    e11 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.e11)

    // you could also initialize like below; is simple and has better readability
    // e11 = findViewById(R.id.e11) as EditText
    
}
```